# Need Category RSS Feed that shows all posts

Tags: categories, rss, templates

How do I go about making this? I've been trying to get add_feed and such but have had no luck.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress generates category feeds automagically. See [WordPress Feeds > Categories and Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds#Categories_and_Tags).

Comment: Yes, but I need to force category feeds to contain all posts from category

Comment: You mean like ALL posts ever posted instead of latest? This isn't really purpose of RSS and will potentially waste crazy amounts of bandwidth. Could you explain a bit what do you want to do with it? Maybe there is a better way and/or format.